# setState() not working, Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Its a simple code and I am trying to use setState state but its yelling the error as in the image

My code:

```
    class PageStatus extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: props.name,
            bb: false
        }
    }
    render() {
        const titleName = this.state.name;
        if (titleName === "Home"){

//---------------------------------------------------------
            this.setState({bb : true}); //this is issue
//---------------------------------------------------------

        };
        return (
            <div className="pageTitle">
            <img src="" width="12" height="18" className={this.state.bb ? 'hide' : ''} />
                
            <span className="page-name">{titleName}</span>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If I use `this.state.bb = true` then it works fine

[Click on this for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEcNR.png)

Comment: you don't need another state. `className={this.state.name === "Home" ? 'hide' : ''}`

Comment: lol.. :) thanks @Emile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you call `setState`, it calls the `render` function, inside your `render` you're calling `setState`, which when triggered, calls `render` again. This repeats over and over, hence the  `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded`  Move the `setState` outside of the `render` function. use [Lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) or event handlers.

Although in your case, you could just resolve the problem by removing the `setState` and doing the following

`className={this.state.name === "Home" ? 'hide' : ''}`

Comment: thank you for clarifying...that was although a prototype.. but yeah my answer is to put the setState outside render()